# HTTP redirect URL with a failed status - retrieving with python requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to retrieve an oauth token request code from a redirected url (returned url contains the code)

Entering my initial url in Chrome developer tools and preserving the log, I can see 3 redirects (status 302) in a row, then a status failed.

The URL with status failed contains an oauth access token I'm trying to retrieve.

Can I retrieve this using python requests library?

EDIT 1:
Code is almost irrelevant - nothing complex here. Also attached the developer tools log. I'm trying to capture the URL of the failed document:

```
# OAUTH
# 1 Gain Token request code
token_request = requests.get(oauth_request_address,allow_redirects=True)
```

[image: developer_tools_log]

Comment: Could you add some code to your question?

Comment: Using requests-oauthlib, I used an oauthsession to request the authentication code. That cleanly handled the redirects